# Simplifying this logarithm series

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, factorial

$$\sum_{i\; =\; 2}^{99}{\frac{1}{\log _{i}\left( 99! \right)}}$$

How would you evaluate (or at least simplify) this logarithm series?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\log_a b = \frac{\log b}{\log a}$, for any choice of base of the logarithm.  (Mathematicians tend to mean the natural logarithm when they write $\log$.)

In particular, $\frac1{\log_a b} = \frac{\log a}{\log b} = \log_b a$.

Therefore your sum is:

$$ \sum_{i=2}^{99} \log_{99!} i = \log_{99!} \left( \prod_{i=2}^{99} i \right) = \log_{99!} 99! = 1 $$

where in first equality I used the well-known fact that $\sum \log = \log \prod$.

Comment: @vadim123 thanks, fixed.  OTOH, you have more than enough reputation to go fix such errors yourself :)

Comment: You wrote that $\frac{1}{\log _{a}b}\; =\; \log _{a}b$. Shouldn't it be that $\frac{1}{\log _{a}b}\; =\; \log _{b}a$?

Comment: @user2612743 sorry, yes.  Man, for a short answer, I had a lot of typos.